# Using Oracle Data Modeler to generate an ERD and running into an issue

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sql-data-modeler

I'm not sure if anyone can help me here, but I've begun the undertaking of attempting to map my databases 846 views into a readable format.

The only issue is, while I am well versed in query writing, the inner workings are somewhat still a mystery to me. I have imported my data dictionary to logical/relational models, but for some reason when I use the View to Table Wizard, the primary keys are not getting found.

I have done some poking around online to learn that primary/foreign keys do not exist on views, as that's exactly what it is, a view. I do not have access to the tables that I know of (someone a little more well versed said this was due to editioning that I can only see the views of tables). I do not know what to Google to remedy that.

As it stands, I just have an exorbitant amount of logical/relational view models on my screen (red and green), but I can't seem to figure out how to go through the view to the table and map out the keys through that way.

I don't know if any of this is making sense, and I really hope someone sees it. I'm going to keep digging. Let me know if I can give anymore information to help answer my question easier.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, figured it out. Right click the main driving table, click Primary Key. Set the primary key, then discover foreign keys. Worked for me.